# Обработка всех символов строки в Java

Tags: eclipse, строки, java, netbeans

Написал программу на Java, одна из функций CountOfVowels находит количество гласных русских букв в тексте

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package workwithstrings;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
import java.util.*;
public class WorkWithStrings {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static int CountSymbolsWithoutSpaces(String s)
    {
        String result="";
        String CopyString=s.substring(0);
        int i;
        int countspaces=0;
        int len=CopyString.length();
        do
        {
            i=CopyString.indexOf(" ");
            if (i!=-1)
            {
              result=CopyString.substring(0, i);
              countspaces+=1;
              result=result+CopyString.substring(i+1);
              CopyString=result;
            }
        }
        while  (i!=-1);
        return len-countspaces;
    }

    public static int CountWords(String s)
    {
        /*String result="";
        String CopyString=s.substring(0);
        int i;
        int CurrentPositionSpace;
        int PreviousPosition=-1;
        int WordCount=0;
        CurrentPositionSpace=CopyString.indexOf(" ");
            if (CurrentPositionSpace==-1)
            {
                WordCount=1;
            }
        do
        {
            CurrentPositionSpace=CopyString.indexOf(" ");
            if (CurrentPositionSpace!=-1)
            {
                if ((CurrentPositionSpace!=0) & (CurrentPositionSpace!=PreviousPosition))
                {
                    //if ((!"-".equals(CopyString.substring(PreviousPosition, CurrentPositionSpace)))&(PreviousPosition!=-1))
                            //{
                                WordCount+=1;
                            //}
                }
                    result=CopyString.substring(0, CurrentPositionSpace);
                    result=result+CopyString.substring(CurrentPositionSpace+1);
                    CopyString=result;                        
                    PreviousPosition=CurrentPositionSpace;
            }
        }
        while (CurrentPositionSpace!=-1);
        return WordCount;*/
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s , " !?.,:;-");

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {

        String word = tokenizer.nextToken();

        arr.add(word);

        }
        return arr.size();

    }

    public static int CountOfVowels(String s)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
           if ((s.charAt(i)=='a') || (s.charAt(i)=='A') || (s.charAt(i)=='e') || (s.charAt(i)=='E') || (s.charAt(i)=='ё') || (s.charAt(i)=='Ё') || (s.charAt(i)=='и') || (s.charAt(i)=='И') || (s.charAt(i)=='o') || (s.charAt(i)=='O')|| (s.charAt(i)=='у') || (s.charAt(i)=='У') || (s.charAt(i)=='ы') || (s.charAt(i)=='Ы') || (s.charAt(i)=='э')|| (s.charAt(i)=='Э')||(s.charAt(i)=='ю')||(s.charAt(i)=='Ю')||(s.charAt(i)=='я')||(s.charAt(i)=='Я'))
           {
               System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
               count+=1;
           }
        }
         return count;
    }
    public static String WordWithMaxLength(String s)
    {
        int MaxLen=0;
        int IndexMaxLen=-1;
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s , " !?.,:;-");

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {

        String word = tokenizer.nextToken();

        arr.add(word);

        }   
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr.get(i).length()>MaxLen)
            {
                MaxLen=arr.get(i).length();
                IndexMaxLen=i;
            }
        }
        return arr.get(IndexMaxLen);
    }
    public static String WordWithMinLength(String s)
    {
        int MinLen=0;
        int IndexMinLen=-1;
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s , " !?.,:;-");

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {

        String word = tokenizer.nextToken();

        arr.add(word);

        }   
        MinLen=arr.get(0).length();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr.get(i).length()<=MinLen)
            {
                MinLen=arr.get(i).length();
                IndexMinLen=i;
            }
        }
        return arr.get(IndexMinLen);
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    String s, substring;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите строку: ");
    s=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введите подстроку: ");
    substring=in.nextLine();
    if (s.indexOf(substring)!=-1)
    {
        System.out.println("Подстрока "+substring+" присутствует в строке "+s);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Подстрока "+substring+" не присутствует в строке "+s);        
    };
        System.out.println("Длина строки "+s+" с учетом пробелов равна "+s.length());
        System.out.println("Длина строки "+s+" без учета пробелов равна "+WorkWithStrings.CountSymbolsWithoutSpaces(s));
        System.out.println("количество слов в строке "+s+" равно "+WorkWithStrings.CountWords(s)); 
        System.out.println("Количество гласных букв в строке "+s+" равно "+WorkWithStrings.CountOfVowels(s));
        System.out.println("Слово с максимальной длиной в строке "+s+" это "+WorkWithStrings.WordWithMaxLength(s));
        System.out.println("Слово с минимальной длиной в строке "+s+" это "+WorkWithStrings.WordWithMinLength(s));
    }
}
```

Получаю следующий вывод

```
run:
Введите строку: 
ау Е Ы Ё
Введите подстроку: 
ау
Подстрока ау присутствует в строке ау Е Ы Ё
Длина строки ау Е Ы Ё с учетом пробелов равна 8
Длина строки ау Е Ы Ё без учета пробелов равна 5
количество слов в строке ау Е Ы Ё равно 4
у
Ы
Ё
Количество гласных букв в строке ау Е Ы Ё равно 3
Слово с максимальной длиной в строке ау Е Ы Ё это ау
Слово с минимальной длиной в строке ау Е Ы Ё это Ы
```

Как видно из вывода количество гласных був считается неправильно. В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прошу прощения дело в том, что некоторые символы с которыми происходит сравнение s.charAt(i) в цикле были напечатаны не в той раскладке (английской), т. е. были не кириллицей.

Answer (score 0):

С логическим или все нормально.
Проблема в другом - отдельные буквы считываются, а `ау` - не считывается как "`а`" и "`у`"

Comment: @Stas0n но ведь функция charAt(int index) возвращает символ (char) в позиции с номером index в строке и в цикле я просматриваю все символы строки, тем самым каждая гласная буква будет учтена в счетчике?

Comment: Смотри - у тебя в строке лежат вот такие элементы после удаления разделителей:
"ау", "Е", "Ы", "Ё" - у тебя первым элементом s является "ау", а не отдельно "a" и "у"

Comment: @Stas0n причем тут разделители? В функции 

    public static int CountOfVowels(String s)
нет никаких разделителей. Доступ к каждому элементу строки осуществляется с помощью метода charAt(int Index), возвращающий символ строки в позиции index и за счет цикла for я прохожу по всем символам строки, проверяя на совпадения с какой-то из гласных букв, и тем самым учитываю все вхождения гласных букв в строку. О каких разделителях идет речь?

Comment: пардон, мой косяк - не посмотрел, где разделители используешь.
уверен, что s.charAt(0) == 'a' ?

Comment: Может ay это не Русские, а **Английские** буковки? @Ivan31, Вы коды (десятичные) всех символов строки напечатайте.

Comment: @avp, в коде были английские буквы.